# Can't build gdal in x64

Tags: c++, build, gdal

I am trying to build GDAL (1.9.2) in x64.

In the instructions, I see:

```
# Uncomment the following if you are building for 64-bit windows
# (x64). You'll need to have PATH, INCLUDE and LIB set up for 64-bit
# compiles.
!IF "$(PLATFORM)" == "x64"
WIN64=YES
!ENDIF
```

And then, lower,

```
# Under win64, symbols for function names lack the underscore prefix
# present on win32. Also the STDCALL calling convention is not used.
!IFDEF WIN64
!UNDEF STDCALL
!ELSE
SYM_PREFIX=_
!ENDIF
```

Can't find a PATH, INCLUDE and LIB specific for x64, or anything else that I should do...

I can build in Win32.

In x64, I get linker errors:

```
LINK : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _OGRFeatureStylePuller
LINK : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _OSRValidate
...
gdal19.dll : fatal error LNK1120: 74 unresolved externals
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: '"c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 
10.0\VC\BIN\link.EXE"' : return code '0x460'
```

I put (to build in Win32)

```
!IFNDEF PLATFORM
PLATFORM=WIN32
!ENDIF
```

Modified to

```
!IFNDEF PLATFORM
PLATFORM=x64
!ENDIF
```

(to build in x64) - And it worked. But only if I build from inside Visual Studio.

I would like to be able to use a bat file (and build alll platform/configurations)
The above - while it builds in VS, it will not build from command line
(with commands:

```
start /b /wait nmake -f makefile.vc clean
start /b /wait nmake.exe /f makefile.vc PLATFORM=x64
start /b /wait nmake.exe /f makefile.vc devinstall PLATFORM=x64
```

The exact same thing builds in Win32...

I can't figure out what is wrong...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To build with nmake command line I had to run the command from a command shell that has the appropriate variables set to build for 64 bits.

This is what I did to set up the 64 bits building environment:

call "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\vcvarsall.bat" amd64

Answer (score 11):

I managed to build x64 version of GDAL under Visual Studio 2012 using steps from http://dominoc925.blogspot.ru/2013/03/build-64-bit-gdal-for-windows.html:

1. Download gdal-1.9.2.tar.gz (or other version of sources) from http://download.osgeo.org/gdal/
2. Unpack to some directory, e.g. `C:\tmp\gdal-1.9.2\`

   If you tried to build GDAL previously (e.g. x86), make sure that the build directory (`C:\warmerda\bld\`) and the source directory are clean from previous build attempt. If unsure, try to unpack sources in a new directory.
3. Start `VS2012 x64 Native Tools Command Prompt`:
   Start -> All Programs -> Microsoft Visual Studio 2012 -> Visual Studio Tools -> `Open VS2012 x64 Native Tools Command Prompt`

   Or run
   `%comspec% /k "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\vcvarsall.bat" amd64`).
4. Change directory to the directory with unpacked GDAL sources:

   ```
   C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC>cd /D C:\tmp\gdal-1.9.2

   D:\trn4\gdal-1.9.2>
   ```
5. Build GDAL with development files:

   ```
   nmake /f makefile.vc MSVC_VER=1700 WIN64=YES
   nmake /f makefile.vc MSVC_VER=1700 WIN64=YES install
   nmake /f makefile.vc MSVC_VER=1700 WIN64=YES devinstall
   ```

You can get your MSVC_VER number from [here](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/variable/MSVC_VERSION.html). GDAL will be built and installed to `C:\warmerda\bld\`.

Comment: A combination of the three answers worked for me. As @Thalia commented, I sat the variables with `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\bin\x86_amd64\vcvarsx86_amd64.bat"`, I had to wipe out the build directory due to a previous x86 install following @Solkar comment and finally @rutsky instructions worked as charm. Rutsky's instructions are much clearer than the ones in the gdal webpage,

Comment: @quimnuss glad to help! I added note about cleaning build/source directories before build. If you have something to add to instructions --- feel free to edit them

Answer (score 3):

You should first somehow make clear to readers of this thread that over the 6 edits you've done yet, the focus of your question changed more than once, as one can see from the [revision history](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/16526181/revisions)

Anyway:
Now it's just a batch vs ide build job issue; try exporting the makefile from VS

**EXPORTING! NOT just opening the package orginal makefile.vc in an editor window!**

, save it under a name different from the package's "makefile.vc" and use that in your batch.

Comment: Thank you. I wasn't aware that I could do that - export a makefile from VS ! The only improvement that VS makefile would have, would be to set the build environment - if I had known, I would have been able to figure this issue so much faster. (Edits to my post: The fact that I tried to build using VS, which helped me track down the problem, and I added that info to the post - did not change in any way the problem, or the scope of the question. Did not mean to confuse the readers... Quite the opposite. Guess not successful.)

Answer (score 1):

"I can build in Win32."

Have you had  built for Win32 BEFORE your Win64 built attempt?

If so, pls attend
http://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/ticket/4636, bottom of the reply list:

> Just to note for anyone else having the issue.. I'll try to look more
>   into this when I can.. but in the meantime, a clean build is not
>   really doing a "clean" so make sure you manually delete your files if
>   you do a 32 bit build before your 64bit build.

You could also try to simply extract the source again at a different directory, in order to have a clean tree and try to build there for Win64.

Comment: I actually noticed the issue of requiring a "clean" even between different Win32 builds (Debug/Release). I have run the "clean" - I have a bat file that just calls "start /b /wait nmake -f makefile.vc clean" - I have also deleted files by hand... It seems that I have to tell it somewhere else that it is x64.

Comment: Note that I am not getting a conflict between target machine and module machine type - as in that ticket - it seems that the _WIN64 tag is either not set or simply ignored.

Comment: Why do prefer spending time on manually sorting things out when your machine could help you on tracking down the issue? Extract it freshly, let the machine work on the built for Win64 and have a cup of coffee meanwhile. ;)

Comment: That is exactly what I want - with a bat file that would build all 4 platform/configuration combinations. :-)

Comment: ;) Well, you could also extract to 4 different directories and build each on its own in a batch, so doing all work in one dir is no k.o. criterion. I wonder why you don`t simply try that - don't you like coffee breaks? ;)

Comment: I am trying to do that - sort of - the thing is, the bat file will not build for x64 - even though I can build x64 from VS.

Comment: I understand you can build now clean trees using VS GUI. The remaining issue is scripting that build process, at least that is what I take from your last comment and the EDIT of your opening post. Right?